# Script to Find and Resample Audio via FFMPEG Fails on Files with double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, gnu-parallel

Why does this script explode when file names contain double quotation marks?

```
for i in **/*.flac; do
     echo "$i"; 
done | parallel -j+0 --eta --joblog /tmp/parallel.log --progress --bar --colsep ' ' 'ffmpeg -i "{}" -ar 44100 -sample_fmt s16 -map 0:a -y -loglevel error -stats -hide_banner -nostats -nostdin "{.}.resampled.flac" && rm "{}" && mv "{.}.resampled.flac" "{}"'
```

I get this error only on files with parenthesis in their names: `"04. Somebody\'s Watching Me \(Single Version\).flac: No such file or directory"`

Comment: I don't see where you've used `find` in your command, so I've fixed your title.

Comment: Because any double quotes in the filename will interfere with the quotes in `echo "$i"`.

Comment: @mashuptwice No, no, no. `echo "$i"` may break [because of `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618), but not because of quoting. Bash (or any POSIX-like shell) does not treat specially quotes coming from expansion of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how GNU `parallel` parses `{}` (or `{.}` etc.) in shell code.

Normally [it's wrong to embed `{}` in shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618) and no quoting within the shell code can help, one can always find a possible string (filename in your case) that will break it. GNU `parallel` is an (the only?) exception, where embedding `{}` is the right way, but for its mechanics to work you *mustn't* quote `{}` (or `{.}` etc.) in the shell code. [`parallel` tries to replace `{}` with the argument *quoted* in the right syntax for the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349488/108618).

In your case the single-quoted string is the shell code. Within it you have e.g. `"{.}.resampled.flac"`. The double-quotes you used interfere with quotes `parallel` adds to make embedding `{.}` in shell code safe. You need `{.}.resampled.flac` without doble-quotes, `{.}` must not be quoted. In case you need to quote some other part of an embedded argument, you can do it (e.g. `{.}".suffix with spaces.flac"` is fine). Remove double-quotes from all instances of `"{}"` and `"{.}…"` in your shell code. Single-quoting the entire shell code is still the right thing.

Considering the above, [`printf` vs `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) and the fact pathnames in *nix [may start with `-`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452793/108618) or may contain newline characters, we can fix your code and get this:

```bash
for i in **/*.flac; do
     printf '%s\0' "$i"; 
done | parallel -0 -j+0 --eta --joblog /tmp/parallel.log --progress --bar --colsep ' ' 'ffmpeg -i {} -ar 44100 -sample_fmt s16 -map 0:a -y -loglevel error -stats -hide_banner -nostats -nostdin {.}.resampled.flac && rm -- {} && mv -- {.}.resampled.flac {}'
```

<sup>(Side note: do you really need `--colsep ' '` here?)</sup>

In Bash `printf` is a builtin that can take an arbitrary number of arguments without risk of throwing an "argument list too long" error. This means you don't really need the `for` loop. The following syntax will work as well:

```bash
printf '%s\0' **/*.flac | parallel -0 …
```